# Summation Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series

prove that:

I am having trouble coming up with a rigorous proof for this.Can I use induction? Can anyone demonstrate?

$$\sum_{i={2^n+1}}^{{2^{n+1}}}{1/i}\ge 1/2$$

Comment: It comes up in the proof of the divergence of the harmonic series, right? Then compare with the equivalent sum, but with $1/i$ replaced with $1/(2^{n+1})$.

Comment: This is related to the proof of Cauchy condensation test.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{i = 2^n + 1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{2^n + 1} + \frac{1}{2^n + } + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n + 2^n}
$$

$$
> \frac{1}{2^n + 2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n + 2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n + 2^n} = \frac{2^n}{2^n + 2^n} = \frac{1}{2}
$$